# When I get a grep command wrong it breaks my bash. How do i get back?

Tags: bash

I've only just started learning with Codecademy this month so I'm very new to it all. Hopefully this is an easy question.

Sometimes I'll screw up entering a grep search and then it will get rid of my command prompt for any further lines and i cant input any new commands. How do i get back to it or fix it?

I tried ctrl+X and ctrl \ and inputting any other commands. in the pic i messed up searching for spanish.txt by not putting a directory to search in and after it I lost the ability to enter any new commands.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xrw6.png)

Comment: Cancel with Ctrl-C.

Comment: Hi Bernie, welcome to stack overflow. Posting pictures of text is generally frowned upon. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 5):

> Sometimes I'll screw up entering a grep search and then it will get rid of my command prompt for any further lines and i cant input any new commands. How do i get back to it or fix it?

It sounds like you're failing to specify input for `grep` to scan, either by naming files on the command line or by redirecting input into it.  In this case, `grep` scans the standard input (what you type into the terminal, in this case), and it will keep scanning that until it detects end-of-file or you kill it.  On Unix (Linux, MacOS), you would achieve the former by typing a Ctrl-D, and the latter by typing a Ctrl-C.